# How to reach Google Servers to complete the setup from China

Tags: google-account

My phone fell from my pocket while on a bike. After a while it was giving me some problems so I decided to resetting it. I'm in China now and I forget that I have to do through all the processes but China is blocking Google's servers so I can't complete the connectivity check.

Comment: Set up a VPN / Shadowsocks on either your PC or a router, then proxy it through. If you have neither... just buy one, you'll eventually need it.

Comment: how do i use it if incase i get it on my pc

Comment: I will detail this in an answer later.

Comment: I don't get it. You can use your device without a Google account, so you don't need to connect necessarily to complete the initial setup.

Comment: @BálintBabics Problem is, the setup wizard checks for connectivity to Google servers, and since we Chinese can't access it normally, this step will take forever. Worse, on recent devices this step cannot be skipped by normal means.

Comment: @AndyYan But if you do not grant any network (data) connection (2G/3G/LTE or WiFi) the phone can't and won't check Google servers due to there is no available data connection so the phone won't try to force reach Google's servers. But maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @BálintBabics No it still will - it's just *that* stubborn. Else we wouldn't have to devote such efforts to it...

Answer (score 3):

As seen in other answers, VPN is the best solution.

In case you don't have a VPN or it fails to connect, do as follows. This won't do any harm to your phone.
    1. Unlock bootloader (if needed) and flash a **custom** recovery (if TWRP is available for your phone, go straight for it) and boot into it
For TWRP:
    2. Tap 'Mounts' and tick 'system'
    3. Tap 'Advanced' and 'File Manager', locate
       Android 4.1 & before: `/system/app/SetupWizard.apk`
       Android 4.2~5.0: `/system/priv-app/SetupWizard.apk`
       Android 5.1 & after: `/system/priv-app/SetupWizard/SetupWizard.apk`
    4. Rename it to SetupWizard.bak
Other custom recovery like CWM:
    2. Navigate to 'Mounts' using volume buttons and press power button to enter
    3. Again navigate to 'mount /system' and press power button
    4. Get a PC (with adb available) and run

```
adb shell mv /system/app/SetupWizard.apk /system/app/SetupWizard.bak
```

Change the path to SetupWizard.apk respectively according to the information above. Then reboot.
After rebooting from recovery, you'll find that the setup screen is gone and there's no more troubles.

Edit: For most highly customized ROMs in China like MIUI and Huawei's EMUI and ZTE's, there may be other setup wizards called mi_SetupWizard.apk or hwSetupWizard.apk or ZSetupWizard.apk, respectively, which exist **along side** the AOSP's one (usually located in `/system/app` regardless of ROM version). Remove them as well.

Comment: Nice one, this is actually exactly the one I used before I learned how to share a VPN. OP's phone might not be rootable or have a custom recovery though. Still, +1.

Comment: Also, to OP: if you were to try this, remember that after passing the setup wizard and going into homescreen, you should revert this change, i.e. put the setup wizard back into where it was and set correct permissions. Not doing so might give you weird problems, e.g. Home key not working, notification shade empty, etc.

Comment: @AndyYan For myself, I always purge (remove completely) the setup wizard directly without hesitation, and so far I have never observed any malfunctions in anywhere else. I'm the one who dares testing out the side effect of the removal of almost everything, and to my surprise, in most cases, there's hardly any side effect beside the disability of the removed function.

Comment: More or less the same, but it did cause issues on _some_ ROMs, and CyanogenMod is one of them. Before one of the commits popped up last spring I remove the wizard too, but from then on I'm starting to experience issues and had to trace back. Anyway, life of us barebone users :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume you already have a VPN, or a Shadowsocks connection that *works globally* (i.e. not just for your browser - all applications on PC must be able to use it). If using Shadowsocks and don't know how to do it, look up another (paid) software called [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com/). I will leave this part out since this is not so relevant.

Connect PC and phone to the same network / same router. Install [Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/) and start it up, the default working port is 8118. Also get the local IP of your PC, for example `192.168.1.2`.

Now, on the phone in setup wizard, it will initially ask you to set up wireless network. At this phase, choose something like "options" or "advanced" so that you could tweak the network's advanced settings. Choose "manual" for proxy type, fill the IP into the hostname field and port into the port field, presumably like this:

[image]

Done. Save this settings and you should be able to proceed with the rest of the setup.