# Update Nexus 7 to a Nougat ROM

Tags: nexus-7, terminal, 7.1-nougat, setup-wizard

I have an old Nexus 7 (picked up from I/O 2012) that got unbearably slow after an OTA upgrade to Android 5.  After seeing hints from early adopters that Nougat [is serviceable](https://cd-rw.org/t/resurrect-a-nexus-7-2012-to-run-as-good-as-new/141/2) on this device, I decided to give it a whirl by following [these instructions](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7/development/rom-android-7-aosp-grouper-t3467514):

1. Connect from PC via **adb** and run:

   ```
   adb reboot bootloader
   fastboot oem unlock
   fastboot flash recovery twrp-3.1.0-0-grouper.img
   ```
2. Hold **Power + Volume Up** to boot into TWRP Recovery Mode.
3. **Advanced Wipe**, selecting all partitions.
4. **Advanced** | **ADB Sideload** | then on PC run:

   ```
   adb sideload aosp_grouper-7.1.2-ota-eng-20170410.ds.zip
   adb sideload "Mini_Dynamic_GApps-7.1.x-20170121.zip"
   ```
5. Ensure **/data** is mounted (checkmarked under TWRP's **Mount** menu).
6. Still in TWRP, start **Terminal** and run:

   ```
   echo "SYSTEMLESS=true" >/data/.supersu
   ```
7. Another **ADB Sideload**:

   ```
   adb sideload "SR4-SuperSU-v2.78-SR4-20161115184928.zip"
   ```
8. **Wipe**, selecting **Dalvik / ART Cache** and **cache**.
9. **Reboot** to system, allowing TWRP to install its app when prompted.

Here are the files I used:

- [twrp-3.1.0-0-grouper.img](https://dl.twrp.me/grouper/twrp-3.1.0-0-grouper.img.html)
- [aosp_grouper-7.1.2-ota-eng-20170410.ds.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=745425885120723367)
- [Mini_Dynamic_GApps-7.1.x-20170121.zip](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=529152257862697269)
- [SR4-SuperSU-v2.78-SR4-20161115184928.zip](https://download.chainfire.eu/1021/SuperSU/SR3-SuperSU-v2.79-SR3-20170114223742.zip)

The device booted up and began the setup wizard, but as soon as I tapped an option to either set up a new account or copy data from an existing one, I got the error:

> Setup Wizard has stopped

[image: Setup Wizard has stopped]

and on repeated attempts:

> Setup Wizard keeps stopping

[image: Setup Wizard keeps stopping]

After some more research, the consensus seems to be it's a [permissions issue](https://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/problems-gapps-cm13-t3258915) with blame ostensibly pointing to the CyanogenMod (presumably now LineageOS) team.  I tried a few suggestions below, but **I could use some help on how to proceed**.

- Swiping down (notifications bar) or trying other "gesture hacks" to get to some sort of system options page to adjust the permissions for the wizard all fail.  The app seems to lock up the device pretty thoroughly into "kiosk" mode.
- I'd love to try [this supposed fix](http://www.deseret-tech.com/journal/cyanogenmod-13-nightly-setupwizard-has-stopped-working/):

  ```
  pm grant com.google.android.setupwizard android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
  ```

  but after booting into the system the device is no longer visible under `adb devices`.  For what it's worth, running the command in a TWRP Terminal doesn't work either (and I'm not sure if it should).
- Mounting **System** in TWRP and running `df` in a Terminal shows the `/system` partition is 98% full, with 16064 [bytes?] available.  I used the same GApps as the guy who wrote the instructions I was following; is it too big?
- In TWRP I was able to rename `/system/priv-app/SetupWizard/SetupWizard.apk` to keep it from running, and that at least got me into the system.  But I can't figure out how to enable Developer Options / USB Debugging (required for adb) or even a Terminal window for that matter.  Tapping repeatedly on **Build number** in the **About Tablet** screen does nothing.
- I could try and grab a Terminal app from Google Play, but I'm hesitant to proceed with setting it up with my credentials under this "Default Owner" profile.  Is it safe to skip the initial Android Setup Wizard altogether and just start using the device?
- I also tried another TWRP Wipe, using the default partitions (Data, Cache, Dalvik).
- I suppose I could try and sideload a Terminal APK.  But... really?

I came here because I didn't want to get too far ahead of myself before getting a second opinion.  I tried to document the steps taken so far as thoroughly as possible (as well in part to help others, since the documentation out there in the wild for all this is a bit scattered and confusing).  I'm hoping this is just a case of me having missed a small detail in the procedure that someone can point out.

---

**UPDATE**

I've done many flash attempts and at the advice of folks here and elsewhere I more recently switched to using:

- [LineageOS 14.1](https://de1.androidfilehost.com/dl/Kl2Rs5bdkDBAqOBVd-qCTw/1493416983/745425885120726669/lineage-14.1-20170423-UNOFFICIAL-aaopt-grouper.zip)
- [addonsu-arm-signed](https://mirrorbits.lineageos.org/su/addonsu-arm-signed.zip)
- [OpenGApps 7.1](http://opengapps.org/) nano (20170426)
- This [gapps-config-grouper.txt](https://nl1.androidfilehost.com/dl/qaWfgpnj3X6qA6DFLmDDiA/1493422644/745425885120692225/gapps-config-grouper.txt) to trim the GApps packages
- I also tried GApps nano with a more documented [gapps-config-grouper.txt](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=95076129884499335982) which I created in an attempt to only install `BatteryUsage` and `CalSync` (was hoping to save on some `/system` space and get the rest from the Play store afterward)

**So instead of Steps 4-7, it's now:**

4. Run on PC:

   ```
   adb push lineage-14.1-20170423-UNOFFICIAL-aaopt-grouper.zip /sdcard/
   adb push addonsu-arm-signed.zip /sdcard/
   adb push open_gapps-arm-7.1-pico-20170426.zip /sdcard/
   adb push gapps-config-grouper.txt /sdcard/
   ```
5. **Install** | Add the three zips (in the same order as listed above).

   [Safely ignore](https://forum.xda-developers.com/lineage/general/root-addon-packages-lineage-os-t3545275/post71106126#post71106126) the "Updater process ended with signal: 4" and "Error installing the zip file" messages.

I was able to bypass the Setup Wizard - by using either the `build.prop` tip Andy Yan [pointed me to](https://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/how-to-bypass-setup-wizard-nexus-5-t3259170), or the four-corner tapping trick Nadav Tasher suggested in his answer.  However I'm still having problems with apps stopping (even those from the Play store).  Presently working on identifying and [granting missing permissions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/143360/error-looping-unfortunately-setup-wizard-has-stopped/156155#156155).

By way of example, while troubleshooting I found `com.google.android.setupwizard` was missing these requested permissions:

```
    android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    android.permission.CALL_PHONE
    android.permission.CAMERA
    android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
    android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
    android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
    com.google.android.apps.now.OPT_IN_WIZARD
```

I was able to grant all of them except the last one, but didn't manage to get the wizard to restart afterward so gave up on that (particularly after being told it wasn't that important anyway).

Haven't gotten a chance to do similar analysis on any other apps - and not that inclined to.  I feel like if things were working right I shouldn't have to be doing this, and am hoping someone can suggest a better way (e.g. a LineageOS tweak or maybe a different GApps?).

Answer (score 2):

Had this problem a couple days ago.
Solved it by bypassing the SetupWizard.
Steps to skip:

1. Tap the `top-left` corner of the screen.
2. Tap the `top-right` corner of the screen.
3. Tap the `bottom-right` corner of the screen.
4. Tap the `bottom-left` corner of the screen.

Repeat this until the SetupWizard skips.

Comment: Holy smokes what kind of super secret Konami code is this!

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: It got me past the Setup Wizard.  Handy to know.  But I'm still getting app crashes from various programs.  Seems something is wrong with my installation.  Based on what I saw of com.google.android.setupwizard, I think my APK's may not have all their required permissions.

Comment: try to give them permissions or update them somehow or reinstall gapps for 7.1.2

Comment: Hmm, it's not just the GApps I flashed.  Other Google apps I grab from the Play Store (e.g. Google app) are also having similar errors.

Comment: thats probably because the google play services is incompatible. it comes with gapps.

Comment: You mean the _Google Play Services_ included in GApps isn't compatible with the _Google_ app from the Play Store?  Is the _Google_ app you get from the store the same product(s) which _gapps-config_ refers to as `Search` and `Hotword`?  Does this mean I can't get _Speech_ or _Text-To-Speech_ either unless I install from GApps?  (I guess that would explain why they're in nano even though they're listed on the store)

Comment: it isnt compatible with the version of android so it crushes when being started by another google app.

Comment: it means that Google Play Services is incompatible with the rom so every app that uses it crushes.

Comment: you need gapps for android 7.1.2

Comment: Oh jeez!  That explains it.  I just figured that's what OpenGApps 7.1 was (i.e. that it meant 7.1.x).  Could you point me to a good GApps to use which is LineageOS-friendly?  e.g. How 'bout [Beans](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/gapps-dynamic-gapps-t3487192)?

Comment: this site has some: http://rootmygalaxy.net/download-android-7-0-nougat-gapps/

Answer (score 1):

The GAPPS is outdated. Android 7.1.2 introduced changes to the Setup Wizard that will break it for older versions. Use the actively maintained [OpenGAPPS](http://opengapps.org/) instead, with the added benefit of choosing the version (mini, micro, nano, etc.) you want, and also make `/system` less occupied. Just wipe everything in TWRP and start from where you sideload the ROM and GAPPS.

Also, just a hint: AOSP is clean but lacks features. If you want to fiddle with more customization, there are plenty of choices out there (e.g. [LineageOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7/development/rom-lineageos-14-1-nexus-7-2012-t3530261)). You also likely won't need to deal with SuperSU if you flash them, as they have built-in SU management.

Comment: Thanks, will try that!  By the way is that LineageOS build you linked to (2017-03-15) the one I should use, or should I go with the [2017-04-23 one listed here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=745425885120726669)?  What does aaopt mean, anyway - is that the maintainer?

Comment: Yup, that's the maintainer. Use the 0423 build (since XDA people reported no major bug) paired with the latest GAPPS so as to avoid bumping into the Setup Wizard issue.

Comment: Apparently `adb sideload` streams the zip [without storing it](https://twrp.me/faq/ADBSideload.html) on the Android device.  I'm going to use `adb push` instead, but if I didn't, I'm curious:  How would I supply a `gapps-config-grouper.txt` and more importantly, where would the installer write logfiles (like `open_gapps_log.txt`)?  It said "Copying Log to /sideload" but nothing was there.

Comment: What are you looking to achieve? You could just install OpenGAPPS without configuring it. Is there an app in the package that you *really* want gone?

Comment: Sideload isn't the "mainstream" way to install - usually we have a copy of those packages on the internal storage. That's why CWM/TWRP has "install from storage" upfront but hides "ADB sideload" in a corner.

Comment: Makes sense. Got LineageOS and OpenGApps installed (and it looks different!) but once again getting the "Setup Wizard has stopped" error on first boot :-S. Used this slightly modified [gapps-config-grouper.txt](https://pastebin.com/raw/M6RFZ0fv) and the logs seem successful.  Most of that config was inherited from where I got it; I think the only one actually _removed_ from stock CM was Email (see 0's in this [earlier test](https://pastebin.com/raw/avepE8yp)). At least this time I can gesture my way into Settings.  Really appreciate all your help; looks like I'll need to poke around some more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57741/discussion-between-rkagerer-and-andy-yan).